# MVC - is it good practice to have multiple AJAX forms on one page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an MVC Razor site and looking at adding about three AJAX forms on a page, inside each form will have a partial.

Is this good practice? Should the page be limited to one AJAX form per page?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to have multiple Ajax forms on a page. That is why you have Single Page Application (SPA) frameworks. It is not so much a technical issue, rather a conceptual issue.

> Does it make sense to have multiple forms on a single page?

If the answer is **Yes** then proceed. I would just think about that question long and hard before proceeding forward.

Answer (score 0):

> inside each form will have a partial.

Not sure what you meant by that.
You can have as many AJAX forms per page as your heart desires. If the forms all post to different resources (Or controllers) there's not real clean way around it. However, if they're posting to the same resource, you might want to re-think that controller's logic.

-Just one man's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirement. There is nothing which stops you from having multiple forms. The usage of form is *generally* for triggering `non-idempotent` requests to the server which potentially changes some state,  however there are cases where multiple forms are used on single page like a page having a details submit functionality as well as an advanced search form which displays the results in a part of the page. Also there are things like Single page Interface.